# jQuery .load div inside toggle

Tags: jquery, html, load, toggle

I have a div with css display none that is displayed with `.toggle` function clicking a button.

That div contains blog comments. When I send a new comment I refresh that div with `.load` function but it toggles the div so I have to click again the button to show it.

Is there any way to avoid this?

CSS:

```
.comments-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="criticas-wrapper">
    <h4 class="media-title" id="toggle_criticas" onclick="ver_criticas()">&#x25BC CRÍTICAS</h4>
    <button type="button" class="reply">Nuevo comentario</button>
    <div class="comments-container">
     // Here are all the comments
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function ver_criticas() {
        $(".comments-container").toggle("slow");

  }
</script>

<script>

  jQuery(document).on('submit', '.comment_form', function(e){  
  event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: $(this).attr("action"),
data: $(this).serialize(),

success:function(data){
 var json = JSON.parse(data);

      $(".errormensaje,.correctomensaje").html("").css({"display":"none"});


$("#comment").val("");
    $('#parent_comment').val("");


if(json.resultado =="correcto"){

    if(json.mensaje){
var notification = alertify.notify('¡Mensaje publicado!', 'success', 3, function(){  console.log('dismissed'); });
 $('#criticas-wrapper').load('<?php echo base_url(uri_string());?> #criticas-wrapper');


    }

}
if(json.resultado =="error"){

    if(json.mensaje){
      //$(".errormensaje").append(json.mensaje).css({"display":"block"});
      var notification = alertify.notify(json.mensaje, 'error', 3, function(){  console.log('dismissed'); });

    }

}
else
{
console.log(data);
}
},
error:function(xhr,exception)
{

}
})
e.preventDefault();


  });

</script>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you show what you are doing?

Comment: You need to show us the code or else how should we be able to tell?

Comment: My guess is that the load is hiding the div again! After loading you need to trigger the event to show it. Or change the css display attribute.

Comment: Fixed, sorry, was using google translate and forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just add a `show()` to the `div` after you reload it.

```
...load(url, function(){
   ...show();
})
```

So right after the load is finished you show it.

Comment: I tried something similar, I put  (".comments-container").toggle("slow"); after the .load but if the .load function have a bit of delay it will first toggle it and then load it so I´ll be at same point.

Comment: Wait a second I'll edit my comment and show you what I mean.